# Generating "unregular" borders with Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

We have the customer requirement that a standard image will receive unregular border and background. Is it possible to generate this in some way using Imagemagick or some other tool?

An example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably.

See this for some border examples: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#fluff

And backgrounds can be acheved with composite.